# Which possible architecture should I use if I working on Micro-Frontend and Micro-Services?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices

I decided to create a project for insurance domain and in that project, I defined 15-20 micro-services.

Back-end

- Micro-Service_1
- Micro-Service_2
- Micro-Service_3
- Micro-Service_n

Front-end

- Micro-Front-end_1
- Micro-Front-end_2
- Micro-Front-end_n

Refer following diagram is just an example of how micro-services will communicate to each other.

[image]

Each micro front-end will communicate with each micro-service.

- micro-fronted 1 ----> micro-service 1
- micro-fronted 2 ----> micro-service 2

[image]

The scope of the project is wide.

So while working with micro-fronted and micro-service which architecture should I prefer?

Here I'm not expecting exact match of architecture instead of that looking for possible architecture that should I use over micro-services.

Comment: The question begs for a subjective opinion on the matter.

However, I would personally avoid microfrontends all together.
As for microservices, I find that hexagonal architecture plays with it really well.

Comment: you ve already picked an architecture (microservices). are you now looking for technologies to best service you, for architecture patterns (like mvc for frontend and layered for backend) or something else?